# React link to another page on drop down menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I tried to link to another page on my responsive drop down menu but sadly it's not working. I am using MUI for the front end and React in the Backend.
My code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/MyShlongIsLongAT/crypto_api_react_project) on Branch David.

Comment: It would be better if you describe more and create a small example in codesandbox to better understanding of your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not attached the Link to the dropdown menu. If you want to switch pages on dropdown menu item click then please wrap the code of menu dropdown option render in Link i.e.,

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
{pages.map((page) => (
 <Link to={page.link} key={page.name}> 
  <MenuItem  onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
      <Typography textAlign="center">
        {page.name}
      </Typography>
   </MenuItem>
  </Link>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `react-router` and `react-router-dom` packages for this purpose. They provide APIs for routing and navigation.

I think this link is very helpful for you:
[Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Happy coding! :)